# Swing Layout: Prevent my components from moving around

Tags: java, swing

I'm coming from a Opengl project and I need to be able to place elements on my screen and that they stay there.

I'm creating an applet that is the same size as the original opengl project (800*480) and I want to be able to place a button 150*50 at the coordinates 100,200.

everything works fine util an events triggers a setSize, then suddenly layout() is triggered and that make my button move to the center of the screen...

how can I work around that ?

I'm currently overriding the layout() of my JPanel but it doesn't feel right ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). It is strongly recommended that you learn to use layout managers effectively and avoid trying to manually position components. Beginners don't understand how to use layout managers effectively and attempt to use manually placement.

However, the tutorial has a section on "Absolute Positioning" that will help you out. However in general this should only be used when you have a drag and drop feature.

Comment: hehe not a complete beginner, just been a reaaaaaaally long time. regarding the manual placement, I'm creating a online editor for an android game so 90% will depends on where the user click... so not great for layouts. Since I have 3 buttons in my interface (the rest being in menus) I need Absolute positioning. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

By default a JPanel will use a [FlowLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html). You'd be better off with something else, for example a [BorderLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html), but there are a number to choose from. Change it with e.g.:

```
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

You can set a border around your button with [`setBorder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border%29).

Comment: Yep noticed the Flowlayout class in my thread in debug. Unfortunately the applet I'm creating won't work with a Layout